# Check for cells containing strings with non-latin letter characters in Googlesheets using Regex but exclude emojis and common symbols

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'd like some help with a regex code. I'd like to be able to look at a string of text and say whether or not the text has any non-Latin characters (e.g. Arabic, Thai, Japanese, etc.). Here's what I want to get.

True = All Latin characters plus emojis, and symbols like •, ’, ”, etc.
False = All non-Latin characters with the exception of emojis, and symbols like •, ’, ” etc.

I'm currently using the below, which kinda works! But it doesn't take into account the emojis, and symbols like •, ’, ”  etc.

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(B2, “[^\x00-\x7F]“), FALSE, TRUE)
```

Here are some examples of what I would like it to do:

Ideal TRUE Match: `I Hope you will Enjoy my Game Content ❤️`
Ideal TRUE Match: `Today’s the day! • Act Fast!`

Ideal FALSE Match: `Hot Like Sun 線上收聽`
Ideal FALSE Match: `حمل التطبيق الان : http://onelink.to/cfq9xu`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IFERROR(BYROW(A1:A5, LAMBDA(x, "und"=DETECTLANGUAGE(REGEXREPLACE(x, "[[:ascii:]]", )))))
```

but to detect Cyrillic try `"[[:graph:]]"` instead of `"[[:ascii:]]"`

or extended like `"[[:graph:] •’”]"`

[image]

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(IF(A1:A15="",,BYROW(A1:A15, LAMBDA(x, REGEXMATCH(IFERROR(
 DETECTLANGUAGE(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(x, "[[:graph:]]", )))), "und|^$")))))
```

[image]

Comment: TYSM for your help! This seems to work _almost_ 100% correct, but I'm getting interesting results from certain things. Like the following items are showing up as TRUE:

1)
  "حلى الطيبين" أبسط و ألذ حلويات زمان? يتحضر في ١٠ دقايق بمكونات كلها في البيت


2)
  ١٠٠ زر لكن زر واحد يخليك تطلع من الصندوق ?? ( سجن العقابات??)


While these items are just showing up as blank:


1)
Nischay Papa se iPhone 14 Mangra hai?


2)
[Katuri 3] My Friend T-Rex | EP34 | KATURI | Katuri Cartoon

Any ideas? TYSM again!